# Matlab image converter issue

Tags: c++, image, matlab, matlab-coder

I want to use the output of Matlab coder for image processing. I created an c++ output from Matlab coder, I would like to use this code for integrating it into some other application. The problem is we dont know exactly how the Matlab coder generates the image matrix into **const unsigned char[...]**. It would be great help if there is any possibility in checking the way it is created. So that we can create the image into unsigned char[..], the same way and convert it back to image.

This is the code generated by Matlab

```
 * multiplyImage.c
 *
 * Code generation for function 'multiplyImage'
 *
 */

/* Include files */
#include "rt_nonfinite.h"
#include "multiplyImage.h"

/* Function Declarations */
static double rt_roundd_snf(double u);

/* Function Definitions */
static double rt_roundd_snf(double u)
{
  double y;
  if (fabs(u) < 4.503599627370496E+15) {
    if (u >= 0.5) {
      y = floor(u + 0.5);
    } else if (u > -0.5) {
      y = u * 0.0;
    } else {
      y = ceil(u - 0.5);
    }
  } else {
    y = u;
  }

  return y;
}

void multiplyImage(const unsigned char img[2115216], double parameter, unsigned
                   char imgout[2115216])
{
  int i0;
  double d0;
  unsigned char u0;

  /*  implements a function that multiplies an image with a parameter */
  for (i0 = 0; i0 < 2115216; i0++) {
    d0 = rt_roundd_snf(parameter * (double)img[i0]);
    if (d0 < 256.0) {
      if (d0 >= 0.0) {
        u0 = (unsigned char)d0;
      } else {
        u0 = 0;
      }
    } else if (d0 >= 256.0) {
      u0 = MAX_uint8_T;
    } else {
      u0 = 0;
    }

    imgout[i0] = u0;
  }
}

/* End of code generation (multiplyImage.c) */
```

I have an issue converting the unsigned char from the cpp file to multidimensional array, according to suggestion given as followed. But I have to represent the data in the format of c[] w[] h[], I am confused how to represent the red, green, blue information into c[] from following. I am confused is this the right way to represent it (as you can see this function is intended to get a const unsigned char[]) and create an output with three dimension c[] w[] h[] matrix. Any help would be great

```
double Marvin_To_UnsignedChar::Convert_To_Marvin_Image(const unsigned char input[])
{
    int Initial_Color;
    for (int Initial_Height = 0; Initial_Height < Height; ++Initial_Height)
    {
        for (int Initial_Width = 0; Initial_Width < Width; ++Initial_Width)
        {
            int red  [Initial_Height * Width + Initial_Width] = input[Initial_Width * Height + Initial_Height];
            int green[Initial_Height * Width + Initial_Width] = input[Height * Width + Initial_Width * Height + Initial_Height];
            int blue [Initial_Height * Width + Initial_Width] = input[2 * Height * Width + Initial_Width * Height + Initial_Width * Height + 1];
            int color((red[Initial_Height * Width + Initial_Width]) (green[Initial_Height * Width + Initial_Width]) (blue[Initial_Height * Width + Initial_Width]));
            double Marvin_Matrix([color][Width][Height]);
            return Marvin_Matrix([color][Width][Height]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The MATLAB coder generates a MEX function under the hood: http://mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/description3.html.  As such, I am pretty sure that this is the same way of accessing matrix values like you would in MEX. Recall that the elements are in column major format when in MEX. As such, given your channel `d`, and your row `r` and column `c`, and given that each slice is `rows x cols`, you would index the array in the following way: `img[d*rows*cols + c*rows + r];.`  Let me know if this works... and if it does, hit me up with a comment. I would like to turn this into an actual answer!

Comment: Hi I am confused, but how to identify the rows and columns, being it a single vector to index the array. Sorry if it being a obvious question. I am pretty new to image processing ! Thanks again...

Comment: I'm assuming you would have to know that ahead of time.  Given the fact that the array size is constant, I am sure that the image is defined somewhere in your MATLAB code for the generation to determine this size.  It isn't an obvious question of course, and it's a good one to ask.  Look in your MATLAB code and see where the image is defined, then figure out the rows, columns and channels (I'm assuming 3 as it's RGB) yourself.  Use the `size()` function in MATLAB to help you figure this out.

Comment: Hi, I could still not figure out how to split the img[] into colors,rows and columns. It would be great if you could provide me an example. I am searching for an example online, but couldnt find one !...

Comment: Assuming you are given `rows`, `cols`, and `numChannels` where these denote the number of rows, columns and channels in your image.  Also, assuming `numChannels = 3`, you can store each channel into separate arrays as so:  `for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) { for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) { red[i*cols + j] = img[j*rows + i]; green[i*cols + j] = img[rows*cols + j*rows + i]; blue[i*cols + j] = img[2*rows*cols + j*rows + i];} }`.  This will store each channel in **row** major format.  That's all the help I'm giving you.  Good luck.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for the reply, its really helpful and learning curve for me. But the issue is I need to return the output as three dimensional matrix as c[] width[] row[], but according to your suggestion, you have produced the arrays as r,g and b... Is it possible to represent the output as `c[] w[] h[]` @rayryeng

Comment: I am also getting an strange issue using **cols** at initial part of expressions for example at `red[i*cols + j]`. I get an error **This can't be used in a constant expression**

Comment: @rayryeng according to your guidance `img[d*rows*cols + c*rows + r];` the `unsigned char img[]` should have the value `img[3*888*794 + 3*888 +794];` but the value of the unsigned char `img[2115216]` which is just 3*888*794 right ? or am I confused over something !...

Comment: This is assuming **zero**-indexing, so going for **0,1,2** for the channels.  Remember, you're in *C* now, so everything starts at ZERO

Comment: Hi, thats perfect, would be great if you could add your comment as answer. But I think I need to post another question regarding the issue I am facing in converting unsigned char into a multidimensional vector as

Comment: Sounds good.  I'll place my answer shortly.  As for your `cols` error, I assumed you knew this ahead of time.  When you figure that out, you can create a constant such that `cols` is equal to how many columns your image has for a single channel.

Comment: What is "`c[], width[]` and `row[]`" supposed to represent?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. The C[] should have the color data and width[] with the width data and row[] to have the row data of the unsigned char[....] as I need to give the output matrix to another class which is stored like `Marvin::img<U16>& in(mInPort.getImg());
for (int c = 0; c < in.DC(); ++c)
{
for (int y = 0; y < in.DY(); ++y)
{
for (int x = 0; x < in.DX(); ++x)
{
double t = in[c][y][x];
out[c][y][x] = U16(t > 65535.0 ? 65535.0 : t);
}
}
}`

Comment: What is "width" data and "row" data?  Are these the **spatial co-ordinates** of where the colour pixels are located?  How are these matrices structured?  Are the colour pixel data row-interleaved (RGBRGBRGBRGB...) or planar-interleaved? (RRRRRR.....GGGGGG.....BBBBB....) ?

Comment: Hi, its planar interleaved.... as we are looping into c first to process the rows and columns of one color index... I should convert the output image I get from const char into three dimensional matrix so that I can use something like `out[c][y][x]= U16(Object.Const_Char_To_Marvin())`

Comment: Then you don't need three matrices at all.  Do something like this:  `for (int c = 0; c < numChannels; c++) { for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++) { for (int x = 0; x < cols; x++) { out[c][y][x] = img[c*rows*cols + x*rows + y]; } } }`  This will go through the image data and place it into a 3D matrix for you.  Once you confirm this is what you want, I'll place an answer for you to accept.  Thanks!

Comment: @rayryeng Thank you so much for your kind response. I just tried to implment it `public:
 int Color; 
 int Width; 
 int Height;
 std::vector<unsigned char> values;
 Marvin_To_UnsignedChar(int c, int w, int h) : Color(c), Width(w), Height(h), values(c*w*h,'x'){}
 unsigned char operator()(int color, int width, int height) const
 {
  return values[Height*Width*color + Height*width + height];
 }
 unsigned char& operator()(int color, int width, int height) 
 {
  return values[Height*Width*color + Height*width + height];
 }`

Comment: That operator overloading should work.  Let me know if it works before I make an answer for you.

Comment: @rayryeng Hi the problem here is I input only the color, width and height values but, I am confused how to get the value of img[char] from the constructor...

Comment: @rayryeng Are the data from Matlab stored in planar interleaved or data row interleaved ? as I need to know it store the marvin image [c][y][x] into unsigned char[....]